# Runtime error while text rendering with Latex using matplotlib

Tags: rendering

I am trying to use text rendering with Latex on Matplotlib for the code:

```
plt.rcParams.update({
"text.usetex": True,
"font.family": "sans-serif",
"font.sans-serif": ["Helvetica"]})
```

However am getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
b'lp'
```

Here is the full report generated by LaTeX:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded 
format=latex)
restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt latex.fmt
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /home/nikita/.texlive2017/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt [INFO]: writing formats under /home/nikita/.texlive2017/texmf-var/web2c
mktexfmt [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=latex, skipped
mktexfmt [INFO]: Total formats: 0
mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0
```

I can't find the format file `latex.fmt'!
Please help me on how to correct this

Comment: Did you get any solution to this problem?